# store array values in a separate row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

Here, I’m inserting the dynamic array values into database table. It’s inserting the data into database table perfectly. But, I need a little bit modification with this code. It’s inserting the data with `,`. But, I want to store the array values in a separate row.

Now I have:

```
  id  field_name

   1   aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd
```

But I need:

```
   id  field_name

   1   aaa
   2   bbb
   3   ccc
   4   ddd
```

How can I achieve that?

```
$choose_general_rules = $_POST['choose_general_rules'];
$choose_no_of_questions = $_POST['choose_no_of_questions'];
$choose_mark_questions = $_POST['choose_mark_questions'];

$choose_question_name = $_POST['choose_question_name'];
$question = array();
foreach($choose_question_name as $value) {
 $question[] = $value;
}
$result_question = implode(',', $question);

$answer_1 = $_POST['answer_1'];
$answer_one = array();
foreach($answer_1 as $value) {
 $answer_one[] = $value;
}
$result_answer_one = implode(',', $answer_one);

$answer_2 = $_POST['answer_2'];
$answer_two = array();
foreach($answer_2 as $value) {
 $answer_two[] = $value;
}
$result_answer_two = implode(',', $answer_two);

$answer_3 = $_POST['answer_3'];
$answer_three = array();
foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
 $answer_three[] = $value;
}
$result_answer_three = implode(',', $answer_three);

$answer_4 = $_POST['answer_4'];
$answer_three = array();
foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
 $answer_three[] = $value;
}
$result_answer_three = implode(',', $answer_three);

try
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO choose_the_correct_answer ( reference_id, general_rules, no_of_questions, mark_each_questions, question, answer_option_one, answer_option_two, answer_option_three, answer_option_four ) VALUES ( :ref_id, :choose_general_rules, :choose_no_of_questions, :choose_mark_questions, :choose_question_name, :answer_1, :answer_2, :answer_3, :answer_4 )");
    $stmt->bindParam(':ref_id', $lastid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choose_general_rules', $choose_general_rules, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choose_no_of_questions', $choose_no_of_questions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choose_mark_questions', $choose_mark_questions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choose_question_name', $result_question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':answer_1', $result_answer_one, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':answer_2', $result_answer_two, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':answer_3', $result_answer_three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':answer_4', $result_answer_three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error Inserting datas into database :" .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: if you want multiple runs, then insert multiple records. either do your insert/execute 4 times, or `insert into foo (a) values ('foo'), ('bar'), etc...` mysql syntax extension

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute a loop for the insert to you get multiple inserts. Also implode turns the array into a string. You need to loop the array and use the $value variable as your input parameter for the bindParam() method.

You also double initialized a variable.

```
$answer_4 = $_POST['answer_4'];
        $answer_three = array();
        foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
         $answer_three[] = $value;
        }
```

the code above it is

```
$answer_3 = $_POST['answer_3'];
        $answer_three = array();
        foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
         $answer_three[] = $value;
        }
        $result_answer_three = implode(',', $answer_three);
```

The result your adding is a comma seperated string. implode turns an array into a string with a demilmeter.

you need a loop to insert the data x times but you need to also loop through each question array too. without the full code I can only advise you.